# Add a new element to list of lists (in R)

Tags: r, list

I create a list of lists in the following way:

```
 key<-112233
 list1 <- list(a = 2, b = 3)
 list2 <- list(c = "a", d = "b")
 mylist <- list(list1, list2)
```

Then, I want to add a new pair to the second list but I would like to key to be the value of `key` defined earlier. When I do

```
 mylist[[2]]$key<-6
```

I get

```
$c
[1] "a"

$d
[1] "b"

$key
[1] 6
```

rather than

```
$c
[1] "a"

$d
[1] "b"

$112233
[1] 6
```

I have tried using `get` or many possible other combinations using `[]` or `[[]]` but nothing seems to work. Please advice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
key<-"112233"
list1 <- list(a = 2, b = 3)
list2 <- list(c = "a", d = "b")
mylist <- list(list1, list2)
mylist[[2]][key]<-6

[[1]]
[[1]]$a
[1] 2

[[1]]$b
[1] 3


[[2]]
[[2]]$c
[1] "a"

[[2]]$d
[1] "b"

[[2]]$`112233`
[1] 6
```

Update as per the comment from @user20650: Rather than converting variable key to string in the beginning, you can also do:

```
mylist[[2]][as.character(key)] <- 6
```

Comment: Beat me by less than a minute! Yes, this works fine as long as `key` is a character. If `key` is numeric, then all the intermediate elements in the list are created as well (with NULL values).